# Bound on the mean value of function involving Hilbert transform

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Consider the integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x|A|^2_x\mathbb{H}(|A|^2_x) \ dx,$$

where $A=A(x,t)$ is a complex valued, compact function (I mean this in the heuristic sense that $A$ vanishes outside of some finite region, and $|A|$ has finite integral), and the Hilbert transform $\mathbb{H}$ is defined as

$$\mathbb{H}(f)=\frac{1}{\pi}P.V. \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{f(x')}{x-x'} \ dx',$$

with P.V. meaning we are to take the principal value of the integral.

Are there any ways to bound this integral?

Comment: Excuse me if I'm slow now, but what is a compact function? Do you mean compactly supported?

Comment: Also, why do you care about this problem?

Comment: @mickep Thanks for the comment. I have added a comment that hopefully clarifies this remark.

Comment: @NickThompson I care because it arose in a computation of an evolution equation I have for a physically relevant quantity, and I do not know how to interpret its behavior, with the exception of looking at its evolution numerically.